# JLabel not appearing on panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

For class I'm supposed to be creating an application that first lets you choose which value you'd like to calculate, then asks to enter the appropriate info. Then when you click "calculate", it SHOULD display the answer. For some reason my JLabel that should be displaying the answer isn't showing up. I've been searching for a solution, but every thing I do, nothing appears after you click "calculate". I am a novice, please help :(

```
package decay.application;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DecayApplication implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame;
JPanel content;
JLabel prompt1, prompt2, prompt3, prompt4, displayFinal, displayIntitial, displayConstant, choose;
JTextField enterFinal, enterInitial, enterConstant, enterElapsed;
JButton finButton, inButton, conButton, calculate1, calculate2, calculate3;

 public DecayApplication(){

frame = new JFrame("Decay Calculator");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

content = new JPanel();
content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 5));
content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

choose = new JLabel("Which would you like to calculate?");
content.add(choose);

finButton = new JButton("Final Amount");
finButton.setActionCommand("finalAmount");
finButton.addActionListener(this);
content.add(finButton);

inButton = new JButton("Initial Amount");
inButton.setActionCommand("initialAmount");
inButton.addActionListener(this);
content.add(inButton);

conButton = new JButton("Constant");
conButton.setActionCommand("constant");
conButton.addActionListener(this);
content.add(conButton);

frame.setContentPane(content);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){new DecayApplication();}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

String clicked1 = event.getActionCommand();
String clicked2 = event.getActionCommand();

if (clicked1.equals("finalAmount")) {
prompt1 = new JLabel("Enter the initial amount:");
content.add(prompt1);

enterInitial = new JTextField(10);
content.add(enterInitial);

prompt2 = new JLabel("What's the constant?:");
content.add(prompt2);

enterConstant = new JTextField(10);
content.add(enterConstant);

prompt3 = new JLabel("How many years have elapsed?:");
content.add(prompt3);

enterElapsed = new JTextField(10);
content.add(enterElapsed);

calculate1 = new JButton("Calculate");
calculate1.setActionCommand("Calculate");
calculate1.addActionListener(this);
content.add(calculate1);

displayFinal = new JLabel(" ");
displayFinal.setForeground(Color.red);
content.add(displayFinal);

frame.pack();

if (clicked2.equals("Calculate")){

    double finalAmount;
String e1 = enterInitial.getText();
String e2 = enterConstant.getText();
String e3 = enterElapsed.getText();

finalAmount = (Double.parseDouble(e1) + 2.0);

displayFinal.setText(Double.toString(finalAmount));
}
}
}

private static void runGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    DecayApplication decay = new DecayApplication();
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is hidden by the lack of indentation: the `if (clicked2.equals("Calculate"))` test is within the first `if` block. Move it outside the block, and your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your method `actionPerformed`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

String clicked1 = event.getActionCommand();
String clicked2 = event.getActionCommand();

if (clicked1.equals("finalAmount")) {
prompt1 = new JLabel("Enter the initial amount:");
content.add(prompt1);

enterInitial = new JTextField(10);
content.add(enterInitial);

prompt2 = new JLabel("What's the constant?:");
content.add(prompt2);

enterConstant = new JTextField(10);
content.add(enterConstant);

prompt3 = new JLabel("How many years have elapsed?:");
content.add(prompt3);

enterElapsed = new JTextField(10);
content.add(enterElapsed);

calculate1 = new JButton("Calculate");
calculate1.setActionCommand("Calculate");
calculate1.addActionListener(this);
content.add(calculate1);

displayFinal = new JLabel(" ");
displayFinal.setForeground(Color.red);
content.add(displayFinal);

frame.pack();

//here should the if-loop end, because here is the end of instructions which should be called after clicking on the button
}
//and here the second if-loop
if (clicked2.equals("Calculate")){

    double finalAmount;
String e1 = enterInitial.getText();
String e2 = enterConstant.getText();
String e3 = enterElapsed.getText();

finalAmount = (Double.parseDouble(e1) + 2.0);

displayFinal.setText(Double.toString(finalAmount));
}
```

Comment: Yeooo, thank you so much bro! Lol, I can't believe that's all it took to make the bloody label show up. Merci encore :)